# Pentagon on an ellipse: maximizing ratio of perimeters

Tags: geometry, optimization, conic-sections, polygons, arc-length

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an ellipse in the Euclidean plane.

Take 5 points on $\mathcal{E}$, forming a convex pentagon $\mathcal{P}$.

Denote by $\mathsf{Perim}()$ the perimeter.

It seems that $\mathsf{Perim}(\mathcal{P}) \leq \frac{\pi}{5}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) \mathsf{Perim}(\mathcal{E})$ with equality only when $\mathcal{E}$ is a circle and $\mathcal{P}$ is regular.

Any proof or reference of this, if true, or counter-example if false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false, if I am to trust GeoGebra. The ellipse in figure below has semiaxes of lengths $3$ and $\sqrt5$. The pentagon has a side $DF$ of length $3$, perpendicular to the major axis of the ellipse, sides $DE$, $FC$ parallel to the major axis, and the fifth vertex $C$ at one of its endpoints.

[image]

Comment: Very nice., and thank you. I don't dare asking if there exists $0<c<1$ s.t for all $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ we have $\mathsf{Perim}(\mathcal{P}) \leq c \mathsf{Perim}(\mathcal{E})$.

Comment: @NathanPortland It seems quite obvious that $\mathsf{Perim}(\mathcal{P})/\mathsf{Perim}(\mathcal{E})\to1$ for eccentricity$\ \to1$.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @Intelligenti pauca.